# Flutter: Overflow error/Faulty scrolling with SlidingUpPanel

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-dependencies

I am using the `sliding_up_panel` package (version `^2.0.0+1`) and I am facing problems with the scroll behaviour of my screen. My `widget` looks something like this:

```dart
return SingleChildScrollView(
  child: SlidingUpPanel(
      // set minHeight to 0 to only show the SlidingUpPanel when clicking on the edit icon
      minHeight: 0,
      controller: sliderController,
      panel: const RenameWidget(),
      body: generateMainBody(context)),
);
```

With this approach I get a UI that looks like this:

[image]

When I click on the edit icon the `panel` of the `SlidingUpPanel` opens as intended:

[image]

However, you can see on the first screenshot that I have an overflow on the bottom resulting the following error:

`A RenderFlex overflowed by 157 pixels on the bottom.`

I was trying to solve this by nesting the `SlidingUpPanel` in a `SingleChildScrollView` as you can see in the code above. This does not solve the overflow and cuts off some of the content on the bottom.

---

Next, I tried moving the `SingleChildScrollView` into the `body` of the `SlidingUpPanel`:

```dart
return SlidingUpPanel(
    minHeight: 0,
    controller: sliderController,
    panel: const RenameWidget(),
    body: SingleChildScrollView(child: generateMainBody(context)));
```

This solved the overflow error but when scrolling down it still cuts off some of the content.

---

This is definitely related to the `SlidingUpPanel` since doing this works just fine (of course without opening anything when clicking the edit icon):

```dart
return SingleChildScrollView(child: generateMainBody(context));
```

I only want the popup to open when clicking on the edit icon. Maybe using `minHeight: 0` is not the correct way to achieve this? How do I make the `body` of the `SlidingUpPanel` scroll correctly?

Comment: Take a look at [this flutter class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html). You don't need a package to achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this flutter class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html). You don't need a package to achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
 return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: SlidingUpPanel(
          // set minHeight to 0 to only show the SlidingUpPanel when clicking on the edit icon
          minHeight: 0,
          controller: sliderController,
          panel: const RenameWidget(),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(child: generateMainBody(context)),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

or u can use flutter modal sheet if you want to open a container from bottom when click a icon or button

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    height: double.infinity,
    width: double.infinity,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
    FlatButton(onPressed: (){
      showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (context){
        return Container(
          height: 200,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Text("This is Bottom modal sheet", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        );
      });
    }, child: Text("open Bottom sheet",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)))
    ]),
  ),
);
```

}